# How to force a whole crate to use a deterministic hasher (even dependencies)?

Tags: rust, cachegrind

I have a fairly large Rust crate with some dependencies. Now, I want to implement some benchmarks. [To get the most stable measurements possible,](https://pythonspeed.com/articles/consistent-benchmarking-in-ci/) I'm using cachegrind with bheisler's [`iai`](https://github.com/bheisler/iai/).

Even after disabling ASLR, there remains some jitter in the measurements. This most likely stems [from the usage of `HashMap`s whose hashers are randomly seeded.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62066007/which-rust-data-structures-are-non-deterministic) I know that I can initialize the `HashMap` with my own hasher and seed that with a pre-set value, but some of my dependencies, like `serde`, contain `HashMap`s on their own, so that is not a comprehensive solution. [In addition, writing something like the below code](https://richard.dallaway.com/2021/01/04/repeat-resume.html#4-predicable-hash-map) to initialize hash maps is a bit ... *much:*

```rust
use highway::{HighwayBuildHasher, Key};
use std::collections::HashMap;

let high = HighwayBuildHasher::new(Key([0123, 4567, 8901, 2345]));
let mut map: HashMap<u8, u8, HighwayBuildHasher> = HashMap::with_hasher(high);
```

How do I eliminate any inherent non-deterministic behavior from the standard library? Is there any way to specify a default hasher, or at least default random seed, for the Rust standard library that affects a whole crate, including its dependencies?

Comment: I don't think there's any provided way of doing so, but if you're insistent you could compile a modified libstd and link against that?